# Python - Split string on first occurrence of non-allowable characters

Tags: python, regex, string, split, pattern-matching

I have some python code where i want to scan and split string on first occurrence of non-allowable characters.

```
import re,string
mystring="my_id=abc-something_123&anything#;?lcdkahck;my_id%3Dkckdkkj_bcjc"
if "my_id=" in mystring:
    mystring = mystring[mystring.index("my_id=") + 6 : len(mystring)][0:100]
    mystring = re.split('[;&#]', mystring)[0]
    print(mystring)
```

What happens in this, I get string correctly where ;&# is coming, but my data can have any unpredictable character put of ;&#.

What i tried drive out these characters

```
allowable_character = '-' + '_' + string.ascii_letters + string.digits
mystring = re.sub('[^%s]' % allowable_character, '', mystring)
print(mystring)
```

But this just filters the string with characters that are not in 'allowable_character'.

What i am trying to achieve is to split string once the character which is not in 'allowable_character' and return that string.

So I want expected output as 'abc-something_123'

Any help is appreciated here

Comment: Given `mystring` as you have shown above, what is the _exact_ output you want, and why?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I want string after 'my_id=' till any character outside '-', '_', letters and digits. So if other characters appears like &, ; or anything, I am trying to get substring. Please let me know if more details are needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use `re.findall` here:

```py
mystring = "my_id=abc-something_123&anything#;?lcdkahck;my_id%3Dkckdkkj_bcjc"
match = re.findall(r'^my_id=([\w-]*).*$', mystring)[0]
print(match)
```

This prints:

```
'abc-something_123'
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim, Can you explain conceptually, I am new to python

Comment: The regex pattern `^my_id=([\w-]+).*$` is applied to your entire input, once.  It captures the content after `my_id=` consisting of only word characters or hyphen.

Comment: I was playing around the solution you've given, It is giving correct value for all types of scenarios except 'my_id=&anything#;?lcdkahck;my_id%3Dkckdkkj_bcjc', here the value of mystring should be blank as there are no allowable characters between my_id= and '&'. The code fails with error                                                             
 match = re.findall(r'^my_id=([\w-]+).*$', sol)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I am not seeing the behavior you describe.  [See this demo](https://rextester.com/SGFCM40531).